# How to unit test a function that spawns child processes?

Tags: c, shell, unit-testing, readline, c-criterion

So after a LOT of trying. I've dumbed down everything to the following:
The test case

```
Test(minishell_loop, test_ls_exit) 
{
    t_minishell sheldon;

    ft_bzero(&sheldon, sizeof(t_minishell));
    sheldon.command_line = ft_strdup("ls");
    minishell_loop(&sheldon);
}
```

I check whether sheldon->command_line exists. which saves the pain of redirection stuff and so forth.
However, if I don't uncomment the executor, my program hangs.
It probably has something to do with #383, but I'm not completely sure.

```
int32_t minishell_loop(t_minishell *sheldon)
{
    if (!sheldon->command_line)
        sheldon->command_line = readline(PROMPT);
    if (!sheldon->command_line && printf("\x1B[1A" PROMPT "exit\n"))
        return (STOP);
    if (!*sheldon->command_line)
    {
        free(sheldon->command_line);
        return (CONTINUE);
    }
    add_history(sheldon->command_line);
    sheldon->tokens = lexer(sheldon->command_line, &sheldon->exit_status);
    if (!sheldon->tokens)
        return (minishell_clean(sheldon));
    sheldon->ast = parser(sheldon->tokens);
    if (!sheldon->ast)
        return (minishell_clean(sheldon));
    // sheldon->exit_status = executor(sheldon);
    return (minishell_clean(sheldon));
}
```

This 'works' as it successfully prints the whole ast shown below:

```
✦ ~/repos/minishell increase_coverage* ⇡ ❯ ./test.out --filter 'minishell_loop/*'

Command_table #1 at 0x55e58678f490
        Command #1 at 0x55e58678f490
                Argument #1: ls
[====] Synthesis: Tested: 1 | Passing: 1 | Failing: 0 | Crashing: 0
```

So I have a few questions:

1. How/can I keep my executor uncommented?
2. if not, are there other ways to test it?
3. If yes, how can I compare that output against what bash would output?

If I uncomment `sheldon->exit_status = executor(sheldon);`

I get the following output:

```
Command_table #1 at 0x561aa47ce490
        Command #1 at 0x561aa47ce490
                Argument #1: ls
[ERR ] Received message identified by a PID '468695' that is not a child process.
```

One of my executor commands:

```
int32_t execute_simple_command(t_command *cmd, t_minishell *shell)
{
    pid_t       pid;
    int32_t     status;
    char        **arguments;

    arguments = get_arguments(cmd);
    setup_redirects(cmd);
    free(cmd);
    status = execute_builtin(arguments, shell);
    if (status >= 0)
        return (status);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        return (wait_for_child_processes(pid));
    reset_signals();
    execute_child_command(shell, arguments);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: explain what problem you are having. Do you not know how to provide input to a program?  Do you not know how to call a function and test the return value? Please show your attempt as a [mre]

Comment: The readline function reads input from the stdin. I don't know how to tell it to read from my test case. @stark

Comment: I wish I could add some sort of minimal reproducible example, but the problem is that I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: I've added some sort of example but it hangs on readline still

Comment: for more up to date info https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion/discussions/480

Comment: `program < file` will provide input lines to `program` from `file`

Comment: If `executor` is where your error is, why are you not showing that code?

Comment: @stark Unfortunately it's not that simple. In that way it would be very hard to make proper test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My program had a few issues.

1. The execute simple command function is only called inside a child process. I had naked returns which crashed criterion. The solution was using `_exit(127)`.
2. `sheldon.command_line = ft_strdup("ls");` should include a new line so that `"ls\n"` doesn't hang.
3. There were more fixes, if you are interested please navigate to [criterions discussion section for the full answer](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion/discussions/480).